# ObjectDisposedException when opening a form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Everything works as it should when I open the form the first time with Form.show(); but after I close it with Form.Close(); and try to re-open it I get a 'ObjectDisposedException'. What do I need to do to avoid this if I need to open the form for more than one time?

Comment: A form object is a one-time-use object.  Like many others in the framework.  Once the form is closed and disposed it is a dead parrot and cannot be revived.  You must create a new instance with the `new` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to instantiate a new Form after closing and disposing of the existing instance.

```
Form form = new Form();
form.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
form.Hide();
```

this wil just hide the form from the user instead of disposing it.
Keep in mind that if the user closes the form, it again will be disposed, so you could prevent that with

```
    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormClosing += Form_FormClosing;
    }

    private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```